# Can application see all WIFI SSID?

Tags: permissions

I read the [Wi-Fi scanning overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-scan), but I am not sure if an application has the ability to read the Wifi access points around me.

I don't give location permissions.
I turn location service OFF.

The application manifest:

> This app has access to:
>   Storage
>   modify or delete the contents of your USB storage
>   read the contents of your USB storage
>   microphone
>   record audio
>   Location
>   precise location (GPS and network-based)
>   Device history and apps
>   Retrieve running apps
>   SMS
>   receive text messages (SMS)
>   Phone
>   directly call phone numbers
>   read phone status and identity
>   Identity
>   find accounts on the device
>   read your own contact card
>   Call and device ID information
>   read phone status and identity
>   Private Wi-Fi
>   view Wi-Fi connections
>   Camera
>   take pictures and videos
>   Images / Media / Files
>   modify or delete the contents of your USB storage
>   read the contents of your USB storage
>   Contacts
>   the find accounts on the device
>   read your contacts
>   Other
>   receive data from Internet
>   read frame buffer
>   change screen orientation
>   change your audio settings
>   view network connections
>   prevent device from sleeping
>   pair with Bluetooth devices
>   install shortcuts
>   uninstall shortcuts
>   connect and disconnect from Wi-Fi
>   full network access
>   control vibration
>   run at startup
>   read battery statistics
>   access Bluetooth settings
>   use accounts on the device

So it can:

- view network connections
- view Wi-Fi connections
- connect and disconnect from Wi-Fi
- full network access

Will it be able to read the WIFI SSIDs around?

I see Android 8 needs at least 1 of the permissions: CHANGE_WIFI_STATE
 So will this be good enough?
On Android 10 will it also need location permissions?

So I understand correct ?
In Android 8:
[image]
getScanResults() only by asking CHANGE_WIFI_STATE (which is not needed from user to approve ?)

Comment: I would strongly recommend not to use the manifest permission text. Instead download the APK file and directly look into the `AndroidManifest.xml` to see the actual permissions (like `android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`), or use an app that is able to analyze/extract the app permissions.

Comment: @Robert I do have it:
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
I used app ops to disable this. but was it enogth to read the wifi arounds?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, an app can see all surrounding WiFi SSIDs with correct permissions**.

This is the main use case for [WiFi analyzer apps](https://www.wifiattendance.com/blog/best-wifi-analyzer-apps-for-android/) (not affiliated, just to show as an example, have been using one of the listed apps).

As for the permissions required, the already mentioned [Wi-Fi scanning overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-scan) states:

1. Android 8.0 & Android 8.1: *any one* of

   - `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`
   - `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`
   - `CHANGE_WIFI_STATE`
2. Android 9: **all** of

   - `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` or `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`
   - `CHANGE_WIFI_STATE`
   - Enabled location services (under Settings > Location)
3. Android 10: **all** of

   - `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` or `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`
   - `CHANGE_WIFI_STATE`
   - `ACCESS_WIFI_STATE`
   - Enabled location services (under Settings > Location)